# VISIO - new row added to external data

Tags: visio

I was wondering if VISIO Pro 2013 has the functionality to automatically create the shapes when a new row is added in the external data?
At the moment for every new row that appears on my excel spreadsheet I need to drag the row on to my diagram in order to create a shape for that row. Is there another way? 
I can have up to 20-30 new rows a day and dont want to drag and drop every row.

Answer (score 0):

not as built in feature.

But since you seems to not care where the new shapes are placed, then you may consider recreating the whole drawing automatically by means of a macro (eg onDocumentOpened)