# Visio VBA Macro recreate drawing

Tags: excel, vba, visio, external-data-source

I have an Excel table linked to a Visio Org Chart using the below steps:

- Organization Chart Wizard
- Information that's already stored in a file or database
- A text, Org Plus (*.txt), or Excel File
- Browse for File Location
- Name="Employee Name"
- Reports to="Manager Name"
- Select Displayed Fields
- Select Shape Data Fields
- Don't include pictures in my organization chart
- I want the wizard to automatically break my organization chart across
  pages
- Finish

**DRAWING IS CREATED FROM EXCEL BUT NOT LINKED YET**

- Data tab
- Custom Import
- Microsoft Excel Workbook
- Browse for File Location
- Select range from worksheet that contains the data
- Select columns and rows to include
- Rows in my data are uniquely identified by the value(s) in the following columns

  - *I select my PK Employee_ID column*
- Finish

**EXTERNAL DATA IS IMPORTED BUT NOT LINKED YET** (see Data tab>External Data Window... no link icon)

- Data tab
- Link Data (within Advanced Data Linking group)
- All shapes on this page
- Data Column="Employee_ID"
- Shape Field="Employee_ID"

  - replace existing links is checked
- Finish

**EXTERNAL DATA IS NOW LINKED** (see Link icon in External Data Window)

This method works and updates successfully when a row is edited in the Excel table and data is refreshed in the Visio drawing however when a row is deleted or inserted in the Excel table the user manually has to relink these changes which defeats the purpose of linking data automatically. Since my HR department does not have access to Visio they will be updating the Excel table daily and would like the Visio Org Chart to update automatically along with it (including any deleted or inserted rows).

I am looking for an automated solution to this problem. I think I may need a Visio VBA macro to automatically recreate the drawing each time there is a change in the Excel table; I have searched thoroughly and it would seem Visio is unable to do this natively according to this post [VISIO - new row added to external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435887/visio-new-row-added-to-external-data).

Once this macro is created I plan to run it periodically using Power Automate and upload to a shared resource for consumption by the business.

I can record a Macro in Visio no problem however how do I get the Macro to create a new document following the above method (Organization Chart Wizard)?

Of course I am open to any alternatives-perhaps I have overlooked something.

Appreciate your guidance in advance!

Comment: *IMHO* it is impossible because Visio cant re-draw OrgChart

Comment: To get updates (insert/delete) I recreate the drawing manually. This manual task can be recorded in a macro successfully. Redrawing it can be automated for the most part, I an missing the VBA to begin the Organization Chart Wizard.

Comment: You can run OrgChart addin with code `Visio.Application.Addons("OrgC11").Run("/toolbar_vert")`. But also you must send a few parameters...